# Ugly functions are non-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to understand proof of theorem 5.5 from [page 119](https://books.google.pl/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA119&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), everything is clear until ,,This implies that $B_0$ (and hence $A_0$) are non-measurable ... $1=\mu([0,1])=\sum_{n\in Z} \mu(B_0) \leq \mu([-1,2])=3$ which is impossible". Pls could someone explain me why it's impossible? Thanks in advance.

I will wrote the whole proof for people who have problem with link:

Let $f$ be ugly. Assume* w.L.o.g that there exist real numbers $a\neq0$ and $b\neq 0$ with $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=0$. For $n \in Z$, define $A_n=f^{-1}[n,n+1)$ and choose $q_n \in Q$ with $|n*a-q_n*b|<\frac{1}{2}$. Define $B_0=A_0 \cap[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}]$ and $B_n=B_0+n*a-q_n*b=\{x+n*a-q_n*b|x\in B_0\}$ for $n\neq 0$.
Then $x \in (A_n \cap [0,1])$ implies that $y=x-(n*a-q_n*b) \in (A_0 \cap [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}])$, i.e., $y\in B_0$, and thus $x=y+(n*a-q_n*b) \in B_n$. Consequently $(A_n \cap [0,1]) \subseteq B_n \subseteq [-1,2]$.
Thus: $[0,1]=[0,1] \cap \bigcup _{n \in Z}A_n=\bigcup _{n \in Z} ([0,1] \cap A_n) \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in Z} B_n\subseteq[-1,2]$.
This implies that $B_0$ (and hence $A_0$) are non-measurable, since otherwise the $B_n$'s, being pairwise disjoint and pairwise congruent, would have the same measure $\mu(B_n)=\mu(B_0)$ and thus** (5) Disasters with Choice $1=\mu([0,1])=\sum_{n\in Z}\mu(B_0)\leq\mu([-1,2])=3$, which is impossible. Consequently $f$ is not measurable.

(*) If necessary, choose real numbers $a\neq 0$ and $b \neq 0$ with $\frac{f(a)}{a} \neq \frac{f(b)}{b}$ and replace $f$ by the function $g(x)=\frac{b*f(x)-f(b)*x}{b*f(a)-a*f(b)}$.

(**) Here we use $\sigma$-additivity of Lebesgue-measure (which requires some choice principle). However, our use of choice principles can be avoided. (some exercise about that)

(5) If $f:R \to R$ is ugly, then its graph is dense in $R^2$.

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: On my PC it works, i tested it on Google Chrome and Mozilla.
If pages are just not loading then you need to scroll a bit a scroll back.

Comment: https://books.google.pl/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA119&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false
maybe this link will work

Comment: Maybe you can just tell us what is in the theorem.

Comment: I edited my question now so you can see theorem ;>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1 \leq \mu[0,1] \leq \sum \mu(B_n)$. Since $B_n$'s are disjoint and they all have the same measure, $\sum \mu(B_n)=0$ or $\infty$. The first possibility is ruled out because $ 1 \leq \sum \mu(B_n)$ and the second one is ruled out because $\sum \mu(B_n) \leq 3 <\infty$.